# Start xend service automatically on boot fails

Tags: ubuntu, xen, boot, service

I am trying to auto-start xend and xendomain service automatically on boot as soon as I log into XEN-dom0 (on Ubuntu server 12.04 x64) so that whey i type : `sudo xm list` the hypervisor lists me all the VMs ..

This is what I type to do that :

```
sudo update-rc.d xend start
sudo update-rc.d xendomains start
```

Also before that I am removing any system startup links for the service  with the following command : `sudo update-rc.d -f <service> remove`

Problem is every time I reboot after the above commands xend service still not started on boot and i have to type a command to start it .. any ideas what might be the problem ?

If i manually type `sudo xend start` .. sudo xm list command works fine. .

Thanks in advance